# Tooltip in Deck.GL custom layer - Trip Routes

Tags: deck.gl

I am creating routes using [Deck.GL Custom Layer - Trip Routes](http://deck.gl/#/examples/custom-layers/trip-routes). I want to show name of route when hovered over any route. How can I do that? I haven't found anything taking me into the direction of solving this problem.